# print particular line of the text document in a new file

Tags: java

I am trying to scann my text document to print all  lines  between these lines `on Thursday` and `3  3`  in  a new one but currently I am just getting `On Thursday` printed in it. How can I fix that?

**Simple:**

```
U.S. stocks dipped at
the open
on Thursday
after 
a persistent 
selloff in the
global bond
markets
overshadowed
slightly better-than-expected
U.S. jobless
3 3
The Dow Jones industrial
claims data
```

**Code:**

```
File file = new File("D:\\hl_sv\\L03MF.txt");

        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("D:\\hl_sv\\L03MF2.txt");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                String outputLine = "";

                if (line.startsWith("Dez  im ServiceCenter am ZOB)")
                        && line != "3 3") {
                     outputLine = line;
                    writer.println(outputLine);

                }


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: To compare String use `string1.equals(string2)` and not `==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this :

```
boolean shouldPrint = false;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   String line = scanner.nextLine();

   if (line.startsWith("on Thursday)") {
     shouldPrint = true;
   } else if (line.startsWith("3  3") {
     shouldPrint = false;
   }

   if(shouldPrint) writer.write(line);
}
```